# Compass watch only compiles once

Tags: css, sass, compass-sass

I've a problem with my new Mac. On my current devices i got compass up and running several times. But with this new one "compass watch" only compiles once a time. After that every change doesn't do anything.

I've tried an Update on Compass and I started with a clean SCSS-File so no CSS failure could cause this.

It does work with --poll but that's just a workaround and i want to understand how it not works. So I'm happy for any solution.

My file structure looks like this:

```
-site
  |--Gruntfile,js
  |--package.json
  |--config.rb
  |--public
      |--css
      |   |--style.scss
      |   |--partials
      |--js
      |   |--app.js
      |--index.html
```

Thanks

Comment: This question has been discussed in depth http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25592225/compass-watch-compiles-once-fails-to-notice-further-changes

Comment: Yeah thanks a lot. I've just tried this but it doesn't work for me.

Comment: Could you include your scss/compass file structure